# Bcm 43143 Hostapd Driver Problem

Tags: raspbian, usb, wifi, raspbian-jessie, hotspot

I am trying to establish an AP media server with Raspberry Pi 2 and was following the Adafruit guide: [setting up a Raspberry Pi as a WiFi access-point](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point?view=all). I have completed that but at the start step my WiFi dongle, which is as same as this Adafruit [item](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2638), has a BCM43143 chipset and `hostapd` could not find a driver.

I have tried `driver=rtl871xdrv` and `driver=nl80211` for the `hostapd` file at `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` but both of them did not work.

I know my Dongle has AP capability because when I try it with `openelec` it works.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can make `hostapd` see or find the correct driver for the BCM41143 chipset? I have read a lot of guides for other chipsets but failed on this one. :(

Comment: This looks like it might be of use:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/357400/how-to-set-my-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card-into-ap-mode

Comment: i will benefit from it but if i am always having problem to apply command from ubuntu to rasbian. For example this guy is saying that update kernel to get driver but my dongle working when only connect to internet. Hostapd is not recognizing the drive in it. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the driver problem. I followed another guide which is http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot and there is a different udhpc configuration at here. Other one was making configuration to dhpc and this one is configates udhpc. And one more point, I did not make `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles first time using hostapd and found this useful for compiling another version of hostapd :

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25921

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.