# Can the official Raspberry Pi wifi dongle used as hotspot?

Tags: wifi, wireless-adapter, hotspot

Apparently, Raspberry has a wifi adapter [in its shop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/usb-wifi-dongle/). I'd like to know if it is possible to use my Pi as a hotspot with it and if it is easy to set up (additional drivers, special version of Hostapd, etc.).

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running the latest Raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wifi dongle uses the BCM43143 chipset (see your link), and according to [other questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41636/bcm-43143-hostapd-driver-problem), hostapd should work (although possibly using another version of hostapd).

Didn't test the dongle myself, but I would assume it works.

Comment: Yes it does work. `iw list` says it supports AP mode